# Circular permutations problem with putting objects into circle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many options do I have if I want to put red boxes and black boxes into circle so that no two black boxes are next to each other? I have 12 red boxes and 4 black boxes. Also all two red and black boxes are same for me.

I know that there will be ${12}\choose {4}$ options completely. And that some of the options will be counted multiple times but I do not know next steps. Can you please show me how to solve this? Thank you

Comment: Try think about 8 red boxes and 4 blackred boxes.  That will get you to ${12 \choose 4}$.  Then think about rotations of the circle (necklaces) and the number will go down

Comment: @Henry I don't understand, what do you mean by that?

Comment: If you stick a red box to the right of a black box to give a blackred box then no two black boxes will be next to each other

Comment: @Henry I know that I can do: red, black, red, red, black, red, red, red, black etc.  Also black, red, red, black, red, red, black, red, red, blacl, red, red, red,...  But I am getting lost wiht permutations of this and how many of options like that is. I know that at the end I have to remove this options from all of the options

Comment: Could anyone show me the solution please?

Comment: So is the complete number of options 42?

Comment: I posted an answer 41, but then corrected it to 43, which I believe is the right answer.

Comment: A more general way to approach such problems is with Burnside's lemma, like in the similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966349/how-many-ways-to-arrange-8-read-beads-and-32-blue-beads-into-a-necklace-such

Answer (score 0):

Count in how many ways you may separate the black boxes with groups of red boxes. You need four groups of red boxes, each non-empty, total sum of red boxes equal to 12. Removing a red box from each group, you may allow the groups to be empty with total sum of red boxes equal to 8. Then you may list all possibilities (or find some clever way to account for them all) like $(8,0,0,0), (7,1,0,0)$ etc, which for short I will write as 8000, 7100, etc.

The idea described in the comments to use blackred boxes again leaves 8 red boxes to be divided in 4 groups, allowing some groups to be empty, so these are just two different interpretations explaining why we need to count all possible (but cyclically distinct) ways to form 4 (some possibly empty) groups of red boxes, with the total number of boxes equal to 8.

So, not seeing a clever way to do it, let me just list them all.
In front of each row I write the total number of possibilities listed on that row.

1: 8000
3: 7100 7010 7001
3: 6200 6020 6002
3: 6110 6101 6011
3: 5300 5030 5003
6: 5210 5201 5120 5102 5021 5012
1: 5111
2: 4400 4040 (note 4004 is same as 4400)
6: 4310 4301 4130 4103 4031 4013
3: 4220 4202 4022
3: 4211 4121 4112
3: 3320 3302 3230 (3203 3032 3023)
3: 3221 3212 3122
1: 2222

So now add the numbers in the leftmost column the sum is 20 (in the first 7 rows) plus 21 (in the last 7 rows), so the total is 41.

So, despite what you might have learned from Douglas Adams, it appears, if my computations are correct, that the answer need not always be 42 ... or did I miss something?

Oh, No, I missed 3311 and 3131 ... but again the answer is not 42 :)